# How to add photos to specific cells in my Excel worksheet from my computer?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This is the code which I used :

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
  Range("C1").Select
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show
End Sub


Private Sub Image2_Click()
  Range("D1").Select
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show
End Sub

Private Sub Image3_Click()
  Range("E1").Select
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show
End Sub

Private Sub Image4_Click()
  Range("F1").Select
 Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show
End Sub

Private Sub Image5_Click()
  Range("G1").Select
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show
End Sub

Private Sub Image6_Click()
  Range("K1").Select
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show
End Sub
```

I want to do this exactly :

- When I click the image tools in my userform if add a photo it will be like : **(1)**
- When I add two photos it will be automatically two part and size will be equal like : **(2)**
- If I add three photos it will be automatically three part and size will be equal like : **(3)**

I want to add photos when I click the image tools in my userform they will apperar in my excel workseet cells which I want (specific cells I want). I especially want to add photos between 1-5 rows and C - L columns and automatically their size will be equal.

I used this code just to add I can't do what I said with this:

[image: What I want to do]
When I used this code photos don't be equal in specific cells when I want and dont be at specific size which I want ( left one is my userform and image tools which i click , right one is how the script add to photos to  worksheet )

[image: what I did]

I need to fix their size automatically. At Katz's script I can add them to specific cells but If I add a photo it's size dont fill the cells which I want or If I add two photos dont fill cells automatically which I want . As a result this script add photos to cell and size which I wrote to script . Not fix them automatically in specific cells as a equal .
(I want to do like first photo but i can at this script second photo )

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
Dim fileName1 As Variant
fileName1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Tiff Files(*.tif;*.tiff),*.tif;*.tiff,JPEG Files (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif;*.jpe),*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif;*.jpe,Bitmap Files(*.bmp),*.bmp", FilterIndex:=2, Title:="Choose picture", MultiSelect:=False)
    If fileName1 = False Then
    'if cancel pressed
    Exit Sub
Else
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Coursebooking").Select
Range("A4").Select 'choose your start range
Dim picture1 As Object
Set picture1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Coursebooking").Pictures.Insert(fileName1)
With picture1
    .Top = Range("A4").Top 'set as needed
    .Left = Range("A4").Left 'set as needed
    .Width = 600 'set as needed
    .Height = .Width * 3 / 4 'set as needed
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i have screenshot but it is need 10 reputation to add it to here

Comment: Also, this is not a "Please write me a script" site. If you are having problems with your script not behaving the way it should and you can't find out why, post your script and we'll look into what goes wrong. Currently there's no script posted. Can you edit your question and post the VBA script that you've written?

Comment: i add to code now @LPChip

Comment: Please post all of the code, not just the one you think gives the error.

Comment: With this code just i add photos . But i cant fix which cells i will add and i cant fix their size too . I think i told that clearly and i show what i meant in link too .. @LPChip

Comment: I'm new to SuperUser but is it wrong of me to post "write me a script" answers anyway because I like puzzling them out? Should I stop because it encourages bad questions?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of your question, you're missing a key piece: Ranges have properties like Left, Top, Right, and Width just like images do. Here's a function that takes in a `Range` object as a parameter, prompts the user to select images, and then fits the images into that range. Key Point: Based on your request, it is written so that aspect ratio is not maintained so pictures may appear squashed or stretched.

```
Option Explicit
Sub testImportPicturesToRange()
    ImportPicturesToRange Range("B3:H10")
End Sub
Function ImportPicturesToRange(rngTarget As Range)

    'Declaration
    Dim picFormats As String, picPaths, picPath, pic
    Dim i As Long, numPics As Long, picWidth As Long

    'Select the pictures to import
    picFormats = "*.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.png; *.tif"
    picPaths = Application.GetOpenFilename("Pictures (" & picFormats & ")," & picFormats, , "Select Picture to Import", , True)

    'Exit if user clicked Cancel
    If TypeName(picPaths) = "Boolean" Then Exit Function

    'Initialize
    i = 0
    numPics = 0
    For Each picPath In picPaths
        If picPath <> False Then numPics = numPics + 1
    Next
    picWidth = rngTarget.Width / numPics

    'Import the pictures
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each picPath In picPaths
        If picPath <> False Then
            Set pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(picPath)
            pic.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            pic.Top = rngTarget.Top
            pic.Left = rngTarget.Left + (i * picWidth)
            pic.Height = rngTarget.Height
            pic.Width = picWidth
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    'Cleanup
    Set pic = Nothing
    Set picPath = Nothing
    Set picPaths = Nothing

End Function
```

---

**UPDATE:** From what I can see in your question, I *think* this is how you would want to implement it.

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
    ImportPicturesToRange Range("C1")
End Sub
```

Comment: How to add to the script to image click tools? @Engineer Toast

Comment: I updated my answer to show an example based on the sample code in your question.